# Popoup on tap google maps overlay

Tags: android

Is possibile to make a popup such as the google maps popup that show when I tap on the overlay ?

I want to make a pop up like this:

[image: snap]

Comment: you can do that by designing a custom dialog and call that whenever user taps on some location

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this excellent project on GitHub!

https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons